# Svg arc clip inner radius

Tags: svg, react-native-svg

I create arc using path like image bellow. Here is my code

```
      <Path d="M50 50 10 49.99999999999999 A40 40 0 0 1 50 10Z" fill="#81c784" />
      <Path d="M50 50 49.99999999999999 90 A40 40 0 0 1 10 49.99999999999999Z" fill="#00838f" />
      <Path d="M50 50 50 10 A40 40 0 0 1 49.99999999999999 90Z" fill="#26c6da" />
```

[image]

How can I clip inner radius like this
[image]

It needs to be a transparent because I use background image. I try with clip path, but it clip arc outside.

```
 <ClipPath id="clip" >            
      <Circle
        cx="50"
        cy="50"
        r="20"
      />
    </ClipPath>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask) to cut a round hole.

```
<mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="150" fill="black" />
  </mask>
```

Opaque circle `fill = "black"` in the mask cuts a hole.
The clear rect `fill = "white"` shows the rest of the arch.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 600" > 
<defs>   
  <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="150" fill="black" />
  </mask>

</defs>
<g mask="url(#msk1)">
    <path fill="#81c784" d="M250,250v250C111.9,500,0,388.1,0,250H250z"/>
    <path fill="#00838f" d="M0,250C0,111.9,111.9,0,250,0v250H0z"/>
    <path fill="#26c6da" d="M250,500c138.1,0,250-111.9,250-250S388.1,0,250,0V500z"/>
</g>
   
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the clip path in this example by creating the inner circle and then appending to the end of the circular portion of the path a rectangle that is outside the shape I am trying to clip and proceeds around the circle backwards. If you extract the clip path from the example below and display it you will see what I mean.

```
<clipPath id="innerClip">
    <path d="M250,375c-69,0-125-56-125-125s56-125,125-125s125,56,125,125S319,375,250,375v185h300l-4-620H-54v620h304V375z"/>
</clipPath>
<g clip-path="url(#innerClip)">
    <path fill="#81c784" d="M250,250v250C111.9,500,0,388.1,0,250H250z"/>
    <path fill="#00838f" d="M0,250C0,111.9,111.9,0,250,0v250H0z"/>
    <path fill="#26c6da" d="M250,500c138.1,0,250-111.9,250-250S388.1,0,250,0V500z"/>
</g>
```